# Where to update database in Android in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I downloaded android in-app billing sample "Dungeons" application and i tested it.But i don't want to use its database.I want to update my own database but i can't find that where can i update my database with purchased response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private class DungeonsPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
    public DungeonsPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(BusinessPunkBase.this, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported) {
            //Here you can update your DB

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState,
            String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime,
            String developerPayload) {
        //Here you can update your DB

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) {
        //Here you can update
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked.I tried in onPurchaseStateChange but there aren't any change.